# how to remove element from List in java

Tags: java, android, arrays

This is reg. a requirement where I need to remove an element from List in java. I am getting unsupported exception when I try to remove element from List. Below is the code:

```
String[] str_array = {"abc","def","ght"};
List<String> results = Arrays.asList(str_array);
String tobeRemovedItem="";
for(int i=0;i<results.size();i++){ 
    if(results.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(searchString)) {
        tobeRemovedItem=results.get(i);
    }
}
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(tobeRemovedItem)) {
    results.remove(tobeRemovedItem);     // I am getting exception here.
}
```

Can anyone help me in solving this issue?

Comment: Please consider using more whitespace. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The type of list returned by `Arrays.asList` does not support the `remove` operation. Hence the exception.

You can use the `java.util.ArrayList` instead.

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str_array));
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered already, but now without indirect datastructure of `.asList()`

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(results, str_array);
```

The .asList is *backed* by the array, hence you can modify the original array be modifying the list. And vice versa you cannot grow or shrink the list, as then the backed array object would need to be exchanged, as arrays are fixed in java.

Answer (score 0):

The size of List returned by `Arrays.asList` cannot be changed. Instead you can do:

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(str_array));
```

Comment: It's not about the size of `Arrays#asList`. It's because the returned `List` cannot be modified.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You can modify this list with `set()` method. It's just the size altering methods which are disabled.

Comment: Arrays.asList() returns Arrays$ArrayList which is a fixed size array similar to a fixed size array

Comment: What you can modify is the backing array (which is done through `set`  method) but as a `List` it doesn't support add/remove operations.

Comment: @KumarAbhinav in fact `Arrays$ArrayList` directly uses the array passed as argument.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza 100% true

Answer (score 0):

In general, `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown by the implementation of an interface (or a child class of a class with an abstract method), where the implementor did not want to support that particular method.

That said, to debug these issues in the future, check which implementation you're using - in this case, it's given via the `Arrays.asList()` method from the [Android sdk](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)). Here you can see it says that it does not support adding or removing of items to the list.

If you must add and remove items, you can wrap the call into the ArrayList implementation of List which *does* support such modification (as suggested by Banthar and khelwood). The [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection<?%20extends%20E>)) takes a list as input, and copies the elements inside.